# How do I replace a text after 10 times of visit?

Tags: php

Lets say I have a sentence and 1 text need to be replaced after 10 visits to the page. the text will change into another text of my choice. How do I do that using php?

Example: The boy is running.

First ten of my visitors will see that sentence. But the 11th visitor will see this:

The boy is walking.

Then the 21st visitor will see:

The boy is swimming.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Looks like you need to learn more about what is expected of users here. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: use a counter that is incremented at each call of the page; in a file or in a database. then use the value to determine what text to show.

Comment: use PHP sessions http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Comment: @MiloLaMar: Sessions are per user.

Comment: Yep, I misread the question. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Every time a user goes to your page or logs in you can increment a variable that lives in a file on your server or from a database.  If you want to make sure it isn't the same user you can store their IP address in your database/file and check for number of "distinct" visitors every time someone hits your site.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Its now giving me ideas.